# Is it possible to have every message signed with digital signature in XMPP (Jabber) protocol?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography, xmpp, xmppframework

Is it possible to have every message signed with digital signature in XMPP (Jabber) protocol? By this I mean not channel encryption over SSL/TLS but exact signing of each message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the sense that there are several standards, including https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-miller-xmpp-e2e, which nobody that I know of has implemented yet, but is liable to be the best starting point.\

No, in the sense that even if your client implemented that protocol, not all of your friends would us it, so "every" is not achievable.